# PHP exec to launch a cmd window with parameters

Tags: php, javascript, cmd

I have been trying to launch a cmd window using the php exec method. The idea is to launch cmd and get it to start running a file. My first problem was being able to rewrite the bat file on the PC when user changes the information such as their user information or what tools they would like to launch. Now that is no longer a problem. I was able to use php popen function to get passed that. From all the reading I have done I was able to determine that it is possible to launch cmd with an additional command telling it to launch the batch file. I just need a good example so I can wrap my head around it. If anybody can help I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the batch file is executable, then you can simply exec it:

`exec('myscript.bat');`

You shouldn't need to do it via cmd.  If you want to for some reason, you will have to provide extra parameters just as you would on the command line:

`exec('cmd /C myscript.bat');`

http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

will show you how to provide other options to cmd (and explain the one above).

Have fun, let me know if you get any problems.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help. I tried what you said, not sure if I am missing something but everytime I try it looks like it completed the function but the batch file has not run on the client side. Sorry I am learning as I go along so sometimes I seem to get stuck. Thanks again and any explanation or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, this is very strange.  I can only imagine that there is a problem with the script itself.  I am assuming it works for you when you run it directly, I suspect that you are trying to access a resource that the web user doesn't have access to.  Could you put your script on pastebin ( http://pastebin.com/ ) ?

As far as explanation goes, when you try to exec a batch file windows should realise what it is and decide to use cmd to run it (first example), if this doesn't work for some reason the second method should do it manually.